# Can you return an instance of a derived class, via unique_ptr, while that static member function was defined in its base class?

Tags: c++

I have defined the following template:

```
//template.h
template <typename E>
class Base{
public:
    Base(const E& identifier);
protected:
    E m_identifier;
}
```

I use a specilization of this template together with QObject as base classes, see the snippet below:

```
//state.h
#include "template.h"

template class Bases<StateIdentifier>;
class State : public QObject, public Base<StateIdentifier>
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
...
}
```

The class `State` above is again used as a base class, see the snippet below:

```
//explicit_state.h
#include <memory>
#include "state.h"

class Init : public State
{
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<Init> generateState()
...
}
```

Now, there can be numerous 'explicit states' which derive from `State`. Can I move the static member `generateState` of `Init` to `State` in order to respect the DRY principle? And still have it return a `std::unique_ptr<Init>` (or any derived class from `State`).

In a nutshell:

```
//state.h
#include "template.h"

template class Bases<StateIdentifier>;
class State : public QObject, public Base<StateIdentifier>
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<State> generateState() //moved here from Init below
...
}

class Init : public State
{
public:
    //static std::unique_ptr<Init> generateState() 
...
}
```

Can I now call `Init:generateState()` and expect it to return a `std::unique_ptr<Init>`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. If the implementation of your base class is aware of the derived class, sure. That's the Factory pattern. You return a Base* that points to a derived concrete class. If each of your derived classes have a 'generateState' function, then it will be name hiding.

Comment: AFAIKS, this has nothing to do with `Base<>`, i.e. this is not a MVCE.

Comment: I don't really understand the question...

Comment: I have made an edit to the question in order to make the question clear.

Answer (score 0):

With template function, you might do something like:

```
template class Bases<StateIdentifier>;
class State : public QObject, public Base<StateIdentifier>
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
    static std::unique_ptr<T> generateState(Ts&&...args)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<State, T>::value);
        return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
};
```